# creating query in C# console (Visual studio 2013)

Tags: c#

hello every one when i create querygenerate Assign dollar will be Error how can i fixed

```
query = "INSERT INTO Question(Image,AnswerA,AnswerB,AnswerC,AnswerD,CorrectAnswer)"
+ $"VALUES("{name}","{answerList[0]}","{answerList[1]}","{answerList[2]}","{answerList[3]}","{name}");";

Error 1 Unexpected character '$' 
Error 2 Invalid expression term '' 
Error 3 ; expected
```

Comment: You have tons of extra `"` in there

Comment: And `'` is the usual quote for SQL strings anyway. Raw input into a query like this  is a terrible idea use Parameterization.

Comment: But this code work on visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the right way to create that script

```
var query = $"INSERT INTO Question(Image,AnswerA,AnswerB,AnswerC,AnswerD,CorrectAnswer) VALUES('{name}','{answerList[0]}','{answerList[1]}','{answerList[2]}','{answerList[3]}','{name}');";
```

And as we always say, We (the community) strongly recommend you to use **parameterized queries**.

Comment: @Sumitkumar Can you tell us what exactly the error says? It is hard to help you unless you can provide details of what you're having trouble with.

Comment: List<string> lstQuery = new List<string>();
            List<string> lstCountryName = getListCountry();

            string query = String.Empty;
            foreach(var name in lstCountryName)
            {
                List<string> answerList=getNameRandom(name,lstCountryName);
                query =     "INSERT INTO Question(Image,AnswerA,AnswerB,AnswerC,AnswerD,CorrectAnswer)"
                        +   $"VALUES( \'{name}\',\"{answerList[0]}\",\"{answerList[1]}\",\"{answerList[2]}\",\"{answerList[3]}\",\"{name}\");";
                
            }

Comment: i want to create text file through programming in which insert command will create to 224 countries with these options...... its too lengthy to create each country name and options....

Comment: how to post all code here ..... its got always error when i paste code here .....

Answer (score 0):

```
 query ="INSERT INTO Question(Image,AnswerA,AnswerB,AnswerC,AnswerD,CorrectAnswer)" + "VALUES("+name+","+answerList[0]+","+answerList[1]+","+answerList[2]+","+answerList[3]+","+name+");";
```

Comment: Error 1 Invalid expression term ''
Error 2 ; expected 
Error 3 Unexpected character '$'

Comment: thanks friends.... i got solution.....output txt file= INSERT INTO Question(Image,AnswerA,AnswerB,AnswerC,AnswerD,CorrectAnswer)VALUES(afghanistan,iceland,afghanistan,andorra,nigeria,afghanistan);